# How to set turns (Python - Tkinter)?

Tags: python, tkinter

I do not know how to set turns properly. The computer seems to skip its turn. I set the first move for the human player and a switch turn function, but the computer does not make its move.
I need to solve this in order to apply your teachings to my tic tac toe game with tkinter.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
root = Tk()
turn = "HUMAN"

def switch_turn():
    global turn
    if turn == "COMPUTER":
        turn = "HUMAN"
    else:
        turn = "COMPUTER"

def computer_movement():
    movement = random.randint(1, 3)
    change_color(movement)

def change_color(n):
    if n == 1:
        button_1.config(bg="yellow")
    elif n == 2:
        button_2.config(bg="yellow")
    elif n == 3:
        button_3.config(bg="yellow")
    switch_turn()

button_1 = Button(root, height=4, width=8, command=lambda:change_color(1))
button_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
button_2 = Button(root, height=4, width=8, command=lambda:change_color(2))
button_2.grid(row=0, column=1)
button_3 = Button(root, height=4, width=8, command=lambda:change_color(3))
button_3.grid(row=0, column=2)

counter = 1
while True:
    if counter == 3:
        break
    if turn == "COMPUTER":
        computer_movement()
    counter += 1

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: please provide more details about the expected behaviour and the current behaviour of the script

Comment: The while loop won't be doing what you expect.  It will execute the three loops before the gui is activated by root.mainloop. You'll need to use tk.after instead, there are many examples throughout SO tagged tkinter.  A  I typed this the code has been edited away.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working for one main reasone the `while` statement before the `root.mainloop()` call.

When you run the program the while this happen:

- the code reach the while loop
- the while loop does 3 cycles and the counter reach the number 3
- the code exit the while loop and the tkinter window is generated.

So the solution was to remove the `while` loop and call the `computer_movement()` after that the turn was assignet to the computer.

Remember that the while loops and tkinter mainloop() aren't best friends, you prefer to handle all the functions llas with the callbacks ( or maybe try to implement `threading`)

```
from tkinter import *
import random
root = Tk()

turn = "HUMAN"

def switch_turn():
    global turn
    if turn == "COMPUTER":
        turn = "HUMAN"
    else:
        turn = "COMPUTER"
        computer_movement()


def computer_movement():
    movement = random.randint(1, 3)
    print('COMPUTER MOVEMENT:', movement)
    change_color(movement)

def change_color(n):
    if n == 1:
        button_1.config(bg="yellow")
    elif n == 2:
        button_2.config(bg="red")
    elif n == 3:
        button_3.config(bg="black")

    if turn ==  "HUMAN":
        print("HUMAN MOVE: ", n)
    switch_turn()

button_1 = Button(root, height=4, width=8, command=lambda: change_color(1))
button_1.grid(row=0, column=0)

button_2 = Button(root, height=4, width=8, command=lambda: change_color(2))
button_2.grid(row=0, column=1)

button_3 = Button(root, height=4, width=8, command=lambda: change_color(3))
button_3.grid(row=0, column=2)


root.mainloop()
```